# Displaying an element similar to p inside a span?

Tags: css, html

I have a span with an inculded p, like this:

```
<span>
    <p>this is the p</p>
</span>
```

This is not allowed according to the HTML5 specs. Now, my HTML is more complex than the above and I need something similar to a p which I can use instead. Which tag could I use or which element can I change using css so it behaves like a p?

Comment: You have two `</p>` tags, should be `<p>this is the p</p>`

Comment: `p` is a whole paragraph, `span` is just a span of text. Please elaborate on what you actually want to show semantically.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a <p> tag inside of a span? Perhaps the <span> is not the best choice? or the <p> tag is not.

Comment: Why not just get rid of the <p></p> tags altogether?  What purpose are they serving?

Comment: `span` is inline, `p` is block level. The two work very differently. Why are you trying to put one inside the other?

Comment: They are displaying 2 lines below each other.

Comment: @user1856596 So you want to drop a line inside an inline element?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: I want 2 lines below each other ...

Comment: @user1856596 in that case, inline elements are the wrong choice here, the top element should be a block element (like a div) and not a `span`, that's not what inline elements mean in CSS.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but it sounds like you don't need the `span`s at all. Wrap the text in `p`s and style `p { margin-bottom: 10px; }` etc..

Comment: @user1856596 it sounds like you are trying to do something more specific than just putting a `p` inside a `span`. Could you update your question to more accurately reflect what you're trying to do?

Comment: I guess Ill change from span to div ... its the best solution. Thats gonna be a lot of work :D. Thanks to all!

Comment: "I guess Ill change from span to div ... its the best solution. Thats gonna be a lot of work :D." - Are you writing html in nano or something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`p` has a [meaning](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

If your content matches `p`’s definition, you should use `p`. Then you should use a `div` instead of a `span` (unless there is no other suitable candidate):

```
<div>
  <p>…</p>
</div>
```

If your content doesn’t match `p`’s definition, you shouldn’t use `p`. Then you could use `span` instead of `p` (if there is no other suitable candidate):

```
<span>
  <span>…</span>
</span>
```

`span` and `div` don’t have meanings. So you only have to consider *where* they are placed syntactically (block vs. inline). You can swap them without losing/changing any semantics:

```
<div>
  <span>…</span>
</div>

<div>
  <div>…</div>
</div>
```

Note that all this doesn’t have anything to do with how these elements are styled. You can style a block-level element with CSS so that it appears as inline and vice-versa: `display:inline;` resp. `display:block;`.