# make my span not take 100% width

Tags: css

I want to have articles next to each other, as much as the browser width allows it. Each article has a fixed width. This attempt does not work each span takes 100% width. I guess because the elements inside the spans are making the trouble, but how to fix this?

```css
span {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<span>
 <h2>Article 1</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 2</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 3</h2>
 <p>Content for article 3. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492256/displaying-an-element-similar-to-p-inside-a-span

Comment: You shouldn't be placing a block element like `p` inside an inline element like a `span`. Read more: [Block vs Inline Elements](http://webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)

Comment: `span` element cannot contain block level elements like headings, divs and paragraphs...it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best thing is to wrap `inline` elements inside `block` elements

best option is to use a `div` element which is `block` which takes a full `width` by default once you add a width it will work perfectly

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*width:200px*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Article 1</h2>
  <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</div>
```

by default span is a `inline` element you can see in the first example which doesnt take any `width` you will need to set it to `display:inline-block`

here is the default demo

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span>
 <h2>Article 1</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 2</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 3</h2>
 <p>Content for article 3. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
```

```css
span {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span>
 <h2>Article 1</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 2</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 3</h2>
 <p>Content for article 3. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
```

If you doeswant the spacing between `inline` element you can use `float` but dont forget to clear the `float`

```css
span {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span>
 <h2>Article 1</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 2</h2>
 <p>Content for article 1. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
<span>
 <h2>Article 3</h2>
 <p>Content for article 3. Bla bla bla bla bla and some more bla...</p>
</span>
```

Comment: That's not the entire story. `h2` and `p` are by default block elements and take full width, stretching the parent `span` too.

Comment: Other answers here mention `display: block;` and one says it is not recommended and I should just use `div` instead. But you're not using `display: block;` but `display: inline-block;` (with the `span`). What is your thought on this?

Comment: Why are you using a span? Use a div for containers. Read my answer >.>

Comment: use a `div` @EricC its a good way

Comment: Could you include a comment in your answer that a div would be preferable (it might reference other answers here), then this would be the perfect answer for me to accept :)

Comment: edited the answe @EricC

Answer (score 2):

Spans are by default inline elements (and shouldn't contain block elements like `h2` and `p`); you either need to make them block elements with

```
span {
  width: 200px;
  display: block; //Turn into a block element
}
```

or a much better option is to **use a <div> instead of a span**, which is already a block element by default and, more importantly, is more [semantically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) accurate.

And here's some further reading on [the difference between span and div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183532/167018).

Comment: Re: "which is not recommended": I agree that using a DIV would be preferable in this instance, but there's no problem changing a SPAN to a block element -- the only thing that defines a DIV as a block element is the browser's default stylesheet -- there's no technical problem with redefining things if you need to.

Comment: There is no technical problem, but there's very little reason to use a span as a block element, instead of a div (which is designed as block element). I mean, we could have <strong> as italics, and <em> as bold but for obvious reasons we don't :)

Comment: There's no reason *we can see*. There may be limitations that the OP has that we're unaware of. I agree that DIV is the most sensible option, though. It's not clear at the moment why it's "not recommended" -- really it's  only because DIV is better suited, not because it will cause problems.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining a scenario where you *must* use a span instead of a div, and you have control over the css

Comment: I've been in the situation  myself, so it can happen. I've made your answer clearer for the OP.

Comment: @HenryC, as mentioned in the question, I am actually not interested in a 3 column layout, just dynamically has as many articles next to each other as the display allows.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then - the main point still stands that you should be using a div not a span (then you can float the divs)

Answer (score -1):

Add `display: block;` to your span's class, or better use div.
Also check this article on w3c schools: [HTML Block and Inline Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

Comment: ok, i did my homework, will be more accurate

Comment: W3Schools has nothing to do with W3C except its similar name, and [it isn't considered a good resource](http://www.w3fools.com/). Better ones are the actual [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) website where you can find official specifications or the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/).